# Run javascript web game (u other graphic app) as standalone

Tags: javascript, game-development, phaser-framework

I created a game in Phaser (phaser.io) and i want to know if there is any way to run it as standalone game (a .exe for Windows in example).

The game it's nothing special: a few .js files, several graphic and sound resources, and nothing more. I want to "compile" all in one executable file (or at least the main .js file) and run it outside the regular navigators.

Are there any way of doing this? Is there any "virgin" navigator engine (by virgin i mean without tabs/favorites/extension/..) that you can put inside .js, .png, .ogg, and other resources, and build it with the necessary info to start an specific .js?

Thanks!

Comment: You could wrap it into a Electron JS app: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest
See that it helps, but there is probably a pahser native way for doing that.

Comment: Right.  If you have seen the Atom editor, or VSCode, or the Windows Terminal, those are all Javascript apps running standalone in a Chrome browser by using Electron.

Answer (score 0):

There are serveral ways, how you could do it, the most *common* (the first that springs to mind, in the javascript/html coding realm) would be:

- electron [link](https://www.electronjs.org/)
- nw.js  [link](https://nwjs.io/)

which one suits you better depends on your use case. Here a [comparison from the electron website](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/development/electron-vs-nwjs#:%7E:text=In%20NW.,be%20an%20HTML%20web%20page.&text=In%20Electron%2C%20the%20entry%20point,HTML%20file%20using%20the%20API.), so take it with a grain of salt. And here a [different a comparison link](https://github.com/Elanis/web-to-desktop-framework-comparison)

**Update:**
I also checked out some *non mainstream* options and **neutralinojs** also sounds very interesting, although it has a smaller *"marketshare"*, but also a *smaller footprint*.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will take a look!