# How to run Phaser games without a local web server?

Tags: phaser-framework

I have been trying to make a phaser game and port it to Tauri so I can have desktop apps, but I need a local web server. How cannot I do it without one?

**Note:** I need it to be **LOCAL**, I can't use tools like Replit or something to host it. (This is not a issue with tauri btw)

Comment: I don't think you have the right tag, \[[tag:phaser]\] is about "a reusable synchronization barrier, similar in functionality to CyclicBarrier and CountDownLatch" in Java. I've updated it, is that javascript framework the one you're using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need a webserver (the webserver "prevent" the [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) security error, for local files), here are some alternatives you can use:

1. **[Electron](https://www.electronjs.org/)** or **[nwjs](https://nwjs.io/)**  as mentioned in this *[SO-Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71152961/1679286)*,
2. Or simply inline all assets/files *(as base64 blobs)*, like you would do for interactive game ads or so *([similar as menitoned in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76324421/1679286))*, than there would be only one big html-file, but you could open it also locally

But it depends on your actual usecase, if it should look like a standanlone app, option 1 is the way to go, BUT it is much more work *(and needs much more space since it deploys it's own "webbrowser")*.
If bundling all assets/files into one single HTML file is enough, I would setup webpack(or another bunlder), like mentioned in the second option. Smaller footprint less work.

**Update:** Checkout [neutralino.js](https://neutralino.js.org/), is a lightweight version of the above mentioned versions, [here a comparison](https://github.com/neutralinojs/evaluation). *(To take with a grain of salt, since it's from the github of **neutralino.js** and it's from 2018)*